# Odoo live chat not working when using apache reverse proxy

Tags: nginx, websocket, odoo, apache2

Now here is the situation i have two servers, one is running apache2 and the other is running odoo with nginx, the server that is running odoo doesnot have a public ip, what i am doing is i am using apache as a reverse proxy that forwards request to the second server through local network ip and nginx handles the rest. The configuation of my apache is below.

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerAdmin sp.example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    ProxyRequests off
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass / http://192.168.0.6/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://192.168.0.6/

    # WebSocket support for live chat
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Upgrade} =websocket [NC]
    RewriteRule ^/websocket/(.*) ws://192.168.0.6/websocket/$1 [P,L]
    ProxyPass /websocket/ ws://192.168.0.6/websocket/
    ProxyPassReverse /websocket/ ws://192.168.0.6/websocket/

    RequestHeader set Upgrade "websocket" env=websocket_upgrade
    RequestHeader set Connection "Upgrade" env=websocket_upgrade

    ServerName sp.spaero.sa
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/sp.example.com/fullchain.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/sp.example.com/privkey.pem
    Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
</VirtualHost>
```

The configuation of nginx on my second server that is running odoo is:

```
#odoo server
upstream odoo
{
  server 127.0.0.1:8069;
}

upstream odoochat
{
  server 127.0.0.1:8072;
}

map $http_upgrade $connection_upgrade
{
  default upgrade;
  '' close;
}

server
{
  root /var/www/html;

  # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
  listen 80 default_server;
  listen [::]:80 default_server;
  proxy_read_timeout 720s;
  proxy_connect_timeout 720s;
  proxy_send_timeout 720s;

  # log
  access_log /var/log/nginx/odoo.access.log;
  error_log /var/log/nginx/odoo.error.log;

  # Redirect websocket requests to odoo gevent port
  location /websocket
  {
    proxy_pass http://odoochat;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;

    add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains";
    #proxy_cookie_flags session_id samesite=lax secure;  # requires nginx 1.19.8
  }

  # Redirect requests to odoo backend server
  location /
  {
    # Add Headers for odoo proxy mode
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_pass http://odoo;

    add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains";
    #proxy_cookie_flags session_id samesite=lax secure;  # requires nginx 1.19.8
  }

  # common gzip
  gzip_types text/css text/scss text/plain text/xml application/xml application/json application/javascript;
  gzip on
}
```

i have tried ngrok on my odoo server and the livechat is working, that means nginx config is correct, but what adjustments i need to make in apache config to make the livechat works or more correct term is how to make websocket work.